# how to route localhost with existing project id in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.2 and developing project management app. In My application I have project created form as new.blade.php in projects folder of view file. new.blade.php

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.store') }}">
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('name') ?: '' }}">
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('notes') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="notes" class="control-label">Notes</label>
                <textarea name="notes" class="form-control" id="notes" rows="10" cols="10">
                  {{ old('notes') ?: '' }}
                </textarea>
                @if ($errors->has('notes'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('notes') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
```

this form data save in ProjectController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'     => 'required|min:3',
            'notes'    => 'required|min:10',


        ]);

        $project = new Project;
        $project->project_name   = $request->input('name');
        $project->project_notes  = $request->input('notes');
        $project->user_id        = Auth::user()->id;

        $duplicate = Project::where('project_name',$project->project_name)->first();
        if($duplicate)
        {
            return redirect()->route('projects.index')->with('warning','Title already exists');
        }   

        $project->save();
```

now I need after save this project data redirect page to users.blade.php file witch situated same projects folder with ulr project id. as example

```
localhost:8000/project/10/users
```

how can I do this? need some help......

**edited**
this is my redirect at projectcontrolle

```
 return redirect()->route('projects.users',[$project]);
```

and routes

```
Route::get('/users', function(){
    return view('projects.users');
})->name('projects.users');
```

Comment: return  Redirect::route(your user route')

Comment: but it is not generated url like **localhost:8000/project/10/users**

Comment: Please can you show your route name for the url: localhost:8000/project/10/users

Comment: Shishir **see My edited answer**

Comment: You route looks like Route::get('project/{id}/users', function(){
    return view('projects.users');
})->name('projects.users'); for url: localhost:8000/project/10/users

Comment: @Jhon Check i edited my answer.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-parameters and https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-named-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You route looks like for url: localhost:8000/project/10/users

```
Route::get('project/{id}/users', function(){ 
   return view('projects.users'); 
})->name('projects.users');
```

After save your project,
First you have to find the project id that you inserted.

```
$project->save();    
$projectId = Project::all()->last()->id;
return redirect()->route('projects.users', ['id' => $projectId]);
```

Comment: after this line $project->save();

Comment: ok it is generated like this **users?id=50** but I need as this **localhost:8000/project/10/users** how can configure this one?

Comment: Do you change your route?

Comment: Your route is not valid for creating url like localhost:8000/project/10/users. So change your route that i answerd.

Answer (score 0):

for this `localhost:8000/project/10/users` url
try this kind of code

// For a route with the following URI: profile/{id}

```
return redirect()->route('profile', [$user]);
```

Comment: 10 is project id not user Id.

Comment: it's just an example change as you like

Comment: Guptha can you give me some sample code here according to My controller. I am new to the Laravel

Comment: ok did as your comments. but my url print as this **http://localhost:8000/users?10**